# POST method through java doesn't work. Can't authenticate

Tags: java, post, jenkins

I'm trying to edit my job in Jenkins through java so I did a URL connection and a request but it doesn't work. My code is the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;


public class JenkinsDesUpdate {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    URL url = new URL("https://$Login:$token@jenkinsURL/job/jobName/21/submitDescription");

     Map <String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("description", "NEW_DESCRIPTION_BLABLA");

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry <String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8")); 
        }


        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic ");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(postDataBytes);
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("POST request not worked");
        }


        /*Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            System.out.print((char)c); */

    }

}
```

What I get is:
POST Response Code :: 200
window.location.replace('/JenkinsURL/login?from=%2FJenkinsURL%2Fjob%2FJobName%2F21%2FsubmitDescription');**Authentication required**

It seems as if I can't authenticate but I pass both the login and the token (It gives the same result with password instead of API token)

Comment: You should be using a `java.net.Authenticator`, not doing this by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is You do not pass anything to authorize your request

```
conn.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic ");
```

you need append your authorized key here

In example:

```
String authString = name + ":" + password;
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
```

Give it a try :) Hope it help you !